# creation makefile, C

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to do a makefile of a simple file.c
but it gives me "nothing to do for everyone"
This is my makefile, what can be the problem?

```
TARGET=custom_find
CFLAGS=-Wall

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Comment: I assume you mean it says _Nothing to be done for 'all'_.  You should always cut and paste error messages (as text not pictures) into questions because the precise wording is often critically important.  Anyway, this makefile doesn't contain any rules that actually build anything, so as long as the `custom_find` file exists, it will say there's nothing to do because you've not put any instructions in your makefile.

Comment: There actually is nothing to do... Please explain what you were expecting to happen.

Comment: A rule consisting solely of a dependency such as `$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c` with no commands should build "custom_find" from "custom_find.c" using Make's built-in implicit rules. If you need to add special options to link libraries etc., you will need to add an explicit command to the rule.

Comment: You don't even need to list `$(TARGET).c` as a prerequisite if that's the format you have for your makefile: make's built-in rules will do that for you.  However, except in the most trivial of cases (where you have a program built from exactly one source file) you will need to do more than this.  Since you haven't actually told us what you need to do to build your program, there's little else we can say.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CC=gcc
    CFLAGS=-Wall -g
    OBJ=fileIO.o 
    EXEC=(nameofthefile)

    $(EXEC): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(EXEC)

fileIO.o: fileIO.c fileIO.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c fileIO.c


clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJ)
```

Make sure you follow this pattern. Would be great if you explain what you mean by " nothing to do for everyone"